# While using union how can I use matrix?

Tags: matrix, union

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union Job {
    char name[32];
    float salary;
    int worker_no;
} Job;

int main() {
    Job u;
    printf("Enter name: \n");    scanf("%s", &u.name);
    printf("Enter salary: \n");   scanf("%f", &u.salary);

    printf("Displaying \nName :%s \n", u.name); /* ① */
    printf("Salary: %.1f", u.salary);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to get name of "Mike" by matrix in union
but it doesn't came out. Why doesn't it came out? When I try this code, it came out with strange word

Answer (score 1):

Not

```
scanf("%s", &u.name);
```

This is right

```
scanf("%s", u.name);
```